# Force Facebook to play videos in background tab

Tags: google-chrome, video, facebook, greasemonkey, autoplay

Recently Facebook added a feature that if I play a video and switch to another tab or a different program from chrome, the video stops playing.

Is there a way to force it to keep playing?

I use Chrome and I don't have flash.

This is not enough to disable that feature:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

Comment: Do you know the method Facebook uses to detect a tab is no longer in front? Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Their code is obfuscated. And it looks like it doesn't happen on firefox. @music2myear

Comment: I'd guess it's javascript, though I suppose HTML5 may include the ability to query the tab state as well. Or, at least, it would surprise me if HTML5 lacked this.

Comment: I had uBlock origin on firefox enabled and on chrome it was disabled on facebook, enabled it again and now this stupid feature doesn't work. @music2myear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just enabled uBlock origin on Facebook again and now I can play videos in the background.

Seriously Facebook, what the hell?

Comment: Why are you blaming Facebook? That's actually a rather convenient feature for most people. uBlock Origin is likely blocking the element(s) Facebook uses for the detection.

Comment: Because it's a very annoying feature that was obviously intended to make sure people actually watch ads, I just want to have a vid playing in the background and to listen to it, that's a fair expectation IMO, taking that option away is not cool.

Comment: Most people? Wow I am not among the most then. And why is it convenient? I would love to know what is wrong in my brain thinking this is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple workaround to execute in the dev console:

```js
document.onblur = null
document.onvisibilitychange = null
```

Answer (score -1):

I developed chrome extension for this :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-allow-background/fkbfhbmobnjpcbpjegogifoeidhmnlel?hl=en